# How to search everything in django restframework using django-filter

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Am i asking is there a possible way of searching from all models, all fields using django restframework 
for example two models are

```
class Shop(models.Model): 
     name=models.CharField()
     description = models.Textarea()
     location = models.IntegerField()
```

and

```
class Bag(models.Model):
       shop = models.ForeigKey(Shop, related_name='bag',on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
       name=models.CharField()
       description = models.Textarea()
       price = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to make it in a way that if a user types any thing that matches any of the fields in the two models, he gets the results, 
how did write my view to support that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a way to do that.  Instead, maybe redesign your models so the common elements live in one model, and the additional elements live in linked models.  E.g.

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField()
    description = models.Textarea()

class Shop(models.Model): 
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    location = models.IntegerField()

class Bag(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop) 
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

Then you can search all the `Entity` objects on `name` and `description`.